# transform file : sum of value - accept or reject

Tags: xslt

I am very new to xslt. I have been looking around how to solve my problem but seem i cannot find what i am looking for.

What I need to transform is: 
sum a total of amount1, amount2, amount3, amount4 
then this total must be less than or equal to OriginalAmount that can be processed (true) otherwise greater than OriginalAmount that should be rejected (false). How to solve this problem?

Here is XML:

```
  <OriginalAmount>1.2100</OriginalAmount>

  <Amount1>1.0000</Amount1>
  <Amount2>0.0000</Amount2>
  <Amount3>1.0000</Amount3>
  <Amount4>0.0000</Amount4>
```

You think it would be easier to write code in xslt or C#, what is your best suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can sum amounts using:

`<xsl:variable name="amountSum" select="sum(root/*[substring(name(), 1, 6) = 'Amount'])"/>`

`root/*[substring(name(), 1, 6) = 'Amount']` is a selector to select all elements that have name beginning with "Amount" - i.e. It selects: `Amount1`, `Amount2`, ...

It would be much easier when:

- Elements have the same name (e.g. `Amount`), the sum would be: `<xsl:variable name="amountSum" select="sum(Amount)"/>`
- All elements in some parent can be summed, the sum would be: `<xsl:variable name="amountSum" select="sum(parentElement/*)"/>` (this sums all elements in `parentElement`)

Then you can compare the values:

`<xsl:if test="OriginalAmount > $amountSum">.. sum is smaller ..</xsl:if>` (It's better to use `&gt;` instead of `>` in comparison)

See [live example](http://www.xmlplayground.com/J7ip6N):

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <OriginalAmount>2.2100</OriginalAmount>

  <Amount1>1.0000</Amount1>
  <Amount2>0.0000</Amount2>
  <Amount3>1.0000</Amount3>
  <Amount4>0.0000</Amount4>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="amountSum" select="sum(root/*[substring(name(), 1, 6) = 'Amount'])"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$amountSum"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="root/OriginalAmount &gt; $amountSum">greater</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>less</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks it looks good, but what does [substring(name(), 1, 6) mean? I have many element names (products, creditdebitflag etc) , how to call these specific element names?

Comment: substring(name(), 1, 6) gets first six characters of element name -> from "Answer5" it gets "Answer". This is used because of the need sum elements of different names. I'll add this to the answer.